# How can I go back to the previous page (using the browsers back button), without throwing any error "Confirm Form Resubmission"

Tags: php, redirect, post, get, back

how can I go back to the previous page without throwing an error Confirm Form Resubmission, 
As what I've searched, i followed some patters such as storing the posted data in a session variable in a extra page from the main page and then redirect the session variable to the navigating page. but it doesn't work :(

This is my code:

**Index.php**

```
  <form method="post" action="Value.php">
    <div id="bar">
    <div id="banner">   
                <img id="img1" src='1.png' height='40' width='200'>
                 &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp 



                <div id ="Login">

                Log-in &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                Username: &nbsp <input type = "text" name = "username" size = "20" maxLength = "40"> &nbsp &nbsp
                Password: &nbsp <input type = "password" name = "pass" size = "20" maxLength = "30"> &nbsp &nbsp
                <input type = "submit" name = "btnlog" value = "Login" id="btn">

                <div id="flip">
                <p> Forgot your password? </p> &nbsp 
                </div>

                </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

**Value.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();

    $te = $_POST['username'];
    $te1 = $_POST['pass'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $te;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $te1;
    $log = $_POST['btnlog'];
    $_SESSION['login'] = $log;
    header("Location: Main.php");

?>
```

**Main.php**

```
session_start();
    $use = $_SESSION['username'];
        $pas = $_SESSION['password'];



        $getInfo = "SELECT user_name,pass_word,id FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$use."' AND pass_word = '".$pas."'";
        $query = mysql_query($getInfo);
        $getSomeRows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION['ids'] = $getSomeRows['id'];
```

Comment: AFAIK only by redirecting them to the same page after success.

Comment: redirect it after success header('location:yoursuccesspage.php');

Comment: Hi Paramore and Mr.Smith! Do i still need to include another php page for that? In my case i used **value.php**